# 'a' or 'an' LGBTQ+ identity?

Tags: articles

I'm just confused as to whether 'a LGBTQ+ identity' or 'an LGBTQ+ identity' is correct. Intuitively I thought the former because 'L' is not a vowel, but Grammarly corrected me to the latter.

I had a similar confusion regarding 'a' or 'an' NGO, but seems like the latter is right because the pronunciation of NGO begins with 'en' — I'm not sure if this is the case for 'LGBTQ' though.

Answer (score 2):

It should be "an" because " LGBTQ+" is pronounced as if it started with "El". In general it is the sound, not the letter, that matters for A vs An.

Answer (score 0):

"A" versus "an" is based on pronunciation, not spelling; the two forms developed because having two vowels sounds next to each other is awkward. Having two vowel *letters* next to each other is not an issue. So it's "an hour", not "a hour" and "a union", not "an union". Whether it's "a" or "an" before "herb" depends on your dialect. Since "LGBTQ+ identity" starts with a vowel *sound*, it takes "an".

Comment: LGBTQ would be spoken as five letters. Other abbreviations you might say individual words. Or some might say letters and some might say words and it might make a difference. UPS = a you-pee-ess or an Uninterruptible Power Supply.